# Is there a limit to the number of vehicles I can store in my garage?

Tags: saints-row-the-third

Courtesy of Steam's wallet abusing summer sale, I am now hooked on the best sandbox game of 2011: Saints Row The Third.  Or, as my friends call the game: the reason respawn won't come hang out with us tonight.

In any case, I love the garage mechanic as compared to the GTA series.  Specifically, I love the fact that you can store a lot of vehicles at once in SR3, as opposed to the GTA method of storing just whatever the heck you can cram in the garage.  But I also love that, once I pimp my ride, it's always available for me at any garage I own, even if I leave it somewhere.  This got me wondering if there is an upper limit to the number of cars that I'm able to store in my garage or if, much like the Tardis, it's really a lot bigger on the inside than the outside.

So, how many rides can a ride pimper keep, after a ride pimper pimps his rides?

Comment: I'm pretty sure it's infinite, but if not, I know it can hold at least one copy of every car in the game :)

Comment: @SadlyNot there must be some limit, computers aren't infinite. It's probably enough to suit most gamers' needs though.

Comment: I am disappointed that this question does not include the phrase "Yo dawg"

Comment: @kotekzot The computer limit for all intensive purposes is not going to be possible to reach unless you spend a lot of hours in the game collecting cars. It's *practically* infinite, if there isn't actually a hard limit set by the game.

Comment: @SadlyNot, there were limits in Saints Row (64) and Saints Row 2 (160), so it stands to reason that there would be a hard limit in The Third as well. (BTW, the phrase you're looking for is "for all intents and purposes".)

Comment: `as opposed to the GTA method of storing just whatever the heck you can cram in the garage` Unfortunately, that is not entirely accurate. Garages in GTA have a limit, aside from the physical space available. When you encounter a garage meant for 2 vehicles, trying to save 3 or more vehicles (i.e. bikes) will only save the last 2. You'll lose the rest, as soon as you load your savegame or the vehicles get de-spawned from getting too far away from them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems to be a bit like Saints Row 2, where the "listed" capacity of the garage was 160, but in practice you couldn't get anywhere near that amount.

My garage is currently full with 89 vehicles in it: like in SR2, all vehicles in a garage (boats, planes, helicopters, and everything else) count toward your max. When you've reached it, you will be unable to store anything more in any of your garages, and you won't be able to customize a new vehicle (but you can customize a vehicle that you or a homie have retrieved from your garage).

89 seems like an unusual number. The Saints Row wiki says there are [85 different vehicles](http://saintsrow.wikia.com/wiki/Vehicles_in_Saints_Row:_The_Third) in the game, but that also seems unlikely, as there are discrepancies within the list. (For example, the Sports09 car redirects to the Torch, suggesting that it's not actually in the game.) I do have duplicates in my garage, but there are a lot of them: 41 unique car/truck/cycle types and 54 unique overall, nowhere near what the maximum is.

Maybe the limit is set for Gen X, 89.0? I don't know. Anyway, it's possible that something about my particular assortment of cars limits what I can add, but in the absence of anything official or better documented, I would go with 89.

Answer (score 1):

Dave DuPlantis cited the Saints Row Wiki, but still gave the wrong answer despite the fact that the wiki contains the correct answer, as well as a full explanation.

As it says on http://sr.wikia.com/Garage - the limit is 64 self-added vehicles, in all 3 games.  Unlocked reward vehicles are not counted towards that limit.  So the limit is 64+X, where X is total number of unlockable vehicles in the game. But you can only add 64 vehicles yourself.  If your garage is full with 64 vehicles, unlockable vehicles will still be added.

The in-game help page for Saints Row and Saints Row 2 says the capacity of the garage was 160, but can be proven incorrect by anyone willing to steal 65 cars off the street and add them to the garage.

In all 3 games, there is only one "master garage list" for all types of vehicles, if you add 64 helicopters, you can add no cars.

The previous answer went on to discuss the number of vehicles in each game, and questioned the accuracy of the list on the wiki: http://saintsrow.wikia.com/wiki/Vehicles_in_Saints_Row:_The_Third
That page states that there are 85 vehicles in the game, which is correct, although the list on that page has several more due to duplicate vehicles used in cutscenes which cannot be obtained.
There are an additional 17 DLC vehicles, which are not counted in the 85.

The previous answer stated that "Sports09" redirects to the Torch page - this is because that is what the vehicle is, and there is no reason to have a duplicate article for it.  The Sports09 is not counted in the count of 85.  Neither are Car 57, Cargo2_m9, Cargo_heist, Eagle_MAD, or HeliMS05.

The previous answer stated "I don't know. Anyway, it's possible that something about my particular assortment of cars limits what I can add, but in the absence of anything official or better documented, I would go with 89." 
The previous reply was correct, in that the submitter *did not know*.
The "assortment of car" does not limit what can be added.  The limit is 64 no matter whether it is 64 cop cars, or 64 different vehicles.  There is no need for "anything official or better", and ANYONE can spend 20 minutes adding cars to the garage to check the limit.  Using cheats will probably speed that up - they also count towards the limit.

(edit: fixed typos)